# Does WebLogic Server 14 support JDK 6?

Tags: java, weblogic, java-6

I want to migrate to WebLogic server 14 but, Could the Weblogic server 14 support old java versions like 6?

Comment: Running Java 6 in 2022 is a seriously bad idea - so this question *should* be moot.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I can not do anything, that software use that version and they want to upgrade weblogic server

Comment: Sounds like your (or their) organization is in a hole, and you / they are running out of ladders to climb to them out of it.  My advice would be to climb one of the ladders that is still available.   Before it rains and they drown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements for various versions of WebLogic can be found in a xls file downloadable from [this page](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/technologies/fusion-certification.html).

WebLogic 14c, in particular, requires Java 8 or Java 11